# Notice: Undefined index: Name in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 7

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a php code (I'm at entry level in php).

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['Name'] = $_POST['Name'];

$_SESSION['Email'] = $_POST['Email'];

$_SESSION['Password']= $_POST['Password'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ","Details");
if(!$con)
{
    echo("hello");
}
mysqli_select_db( $con,"Details" );
$value = isset($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name'] : '';
$value1 = isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : '';
$value2 = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$sql = "insert into details1 ( Name, Email, Password ) values ( '$Name', '$Email',     '$Password' )";

echo "1 record is added";
mysqli_close($con); 
 ?>
```

I'm getting the following notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Name in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: Password in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: Name in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: Email in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: Password in C:\wamp\www\newlogin\data1.php on line 22
1 record is added
```

How to resolve these notices?

Comment: where is HTML code? do you have name parameter in form elements?

Comment: put your form here. and check that `method="post"` or `method="get"`

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST` even makes it to your script? Check for `$_POST` at the top of your script.

Comment: and btw are not executing sql.

Comment: This is you not getting post data being sent back - and trying to execute code that expects an array of post data.

Comment: Check [the notes for the `session_start` function](http://www.php.net/session_start): _"To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser."_ <- you have the `<html>` opening tag before you call `session_start`

Comment: also insert query is not executed.

mysql_query($sql)

is needed

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve these notices?

Easy. Code to make sure errors are caught.

First you are not checking if the `$_POST` value is actually set when setting `$_SESSION` so I have reworked your code to factor that in as well. I also optimized it so the code rolls through an array of `$_POST` values and sets the session appropriately.

Then in the MySQL area you are setting `$value`, `$value1` & `$value2` but then you are using `$Name`, `$Email` & `$Password`. Why? Just set those to be `$Name`, `$Email` & `$Password`. I have also set that to roll through an array of `$_POST` values to set values via `$$post_value`.

```
<?php 
session_start();

// Set an array of post values.    
$post_array = array('Name','Email','Password');

// Roll through the array of post values and set the session as appropriate.
foreach ($post_array as $post_value) {
  $_SESSION[$post_value] = isset($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ","Details");
if(!$con) {
  echo("hello");
}
mysqli_select_db( $con,"Details" );

// Roll through the array of post values and set the session as appropriate.
foreach ($post_array as $post_value) {
  $$post_value = isset($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
}

$sql = "insert into details1 ( Name, Email, Password ) values ( '$Name', '$Email',     '$Password' )";

echo "1 record is added";
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: How about checking the return value of `session_start`, because I bet you it's returning `false` here